# What is the base form called of a superlative or comparative adjective?

Tags: single-word-requests, comparatives, superlative-degree

**Motivation:**  I'm doing a text-mining project and I'd like to map all forms of an adjective to their "base-form".

**Example**:

```
bigger    -> big
biggest   -> big
stronger  -> strong
strongest -> strong
```

The words on the left are the comparitive or superlative forms of the word on the right.

**Question**: What is the word on the right called?

**Related**: [Antonym of "superlative"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30043/antonym-of-superlative), but in this case I'm not looking for the opposite, simply the name of the form *without* the comparison.

Comment: I don't have a reference to back it up, but I believe it is called the "root".

Comment: @KitZ.Fox - Please post this as an answer. Do a google search for root word and use that for the source - I don't want to steal your answer, and the others are wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called  [**positive degree**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/positive_degree).[Wiktionary]

> e.g. When we speak of one person or thing, we use the positive degree (of an adjective).

Comment: The Wiktionary seems to back you up on this, it might be nice to add this as a link to your answer. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/positive_degree

Comment: Hooked @The entry in Wiktionary is not attributed to any authoritative  source.

Comment: I have added the link.

Answer (score -1):

The word you're looking for is '**plain**'.

Adjectives inflect for grade: they have three forms:

**Plain**: tall

**Comparative**: taller

**Superlative**: tallest

(Note: The term "plain" is the one introduced by Huddleston & Pullum in their grammar: 'The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language'.)

Comment: Please can you add a source for this. I have never heard of a root word referred to as 'plain' before.

Comment: @Jascol CGEL, i.e. The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language (Huddleston & Pullum).  (re-messaged - forgot the @ !)

Comment: @BillJ: It's better to edit your answer to include the reference there.

Comment: @sumelic  Good point -  I've just edited my answer.

Comment: Huddleston & Pullum by no means dictates acceptable usage, especially in terminology. This is non-standard, appearing in none of the dictionaries I've consulted. I've not seen it in other works on grammar, either, where 'positive [degree]' or 'absolute' are used. So "The word you're looking for is 'plain' " is unwarranted.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth What a totally negative and useless comment, like most of yours in fact.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth If I choose to subscribe to H&P’s grammar and to pass on their expertise, that’s a matter for me, and not for you to criticise. Deal with it.

Comment: If you post it as an arrogation (The word you're looking for is 'plain'.), I'll downvote it where I think it's merely one option, especially where it's non-standard. Does McCawley use the term? 'H & P use the term ...' is acceptable.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth If downvoting gives you some satisfaction, then go ahead. I'll be sure to let H&P know that they're wrong. Btw, I introduced the term 'plain' at my school some years ago, and it was widely accepted as being ideal, not just for adjectives, but also for  nouns and verbs.